# Make One Activity for multiple Objects

Tags: android

I want to make just ONE activity for my Expandablelist child's.I have Multiple objects  and I want to set onChildClick to open just one activity but change the name and profession and his/hers images.
these are what my objects look like:

```
`--------------------------------------
|Name | Lastname | Profession| ImagePathIndex
----------------------------------------
|Sara | Cliffton | Maid      | image[0]
|John | Williams | Gardener  | image[1]
|Jake | Peralta  | Detective | image[2]`
```

How Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so on expandable child listener you have to pass some extra filed that you want in detail activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String strName = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

And in detail activity you have to get that extra string here is name,image path and so on.

```
String newString;
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    newString= null;
} else {
    newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
} else {
newString= (String) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

one main thing is when you back press from detail activity you have to call finsih() so no stack for all click this is it what you want.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative, You can use **SharedPreferences**.

**[SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)** class provides general types of framework that allows us to save and retrieve the persistent **`key-value pairs`** of the primitive data types like **booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings**. This data will be persevered to the user sessions if your application is killed.

You can check **[Passing data in Android using sharedPreferences](http://codetheandroid.blogspot.in/2012/06/passing-data-in-android-using.html)**

Comment: is it Faster? I have about 70 objects that need about 10 string for constructor...and I need to update it atleast once a week

Comment: @Lucifer Yes its faster . You can use it .

Comment: @Lucifer Please check http://codeblow.com/questions/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-sqlite-and-shared-preferences/

Comment: I used SharedPreferences with SQlite before but I dont know how to make onChildClick listener to open the related sharedpreferences.
Do I have to make a independent Sharedpreference for each object?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the object as intent extra. To pass object with an intent, your object must implement parcelable. You can read about it in the link.

http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-android-s-parcelable-class-a-tutorial.html